# 2 space Text File STORAGE with LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

I created a Text Plane File .txt from Storage with Laravel, but it is always in the first Row, put 2 spaces, I haven't been able to delete it.

I used trim(), ltrim(), replace() etc with php.

Thanks you.

1. To result of text plain:

```
 $ruta = 'pila/' . $anio . '/' . $mes;

        $nombreArchivo = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '_' . $datosEmpresa['TIDE'] . '_' . $datosEmpresa['IDEM'] . '_' . $datosEmpresa['OPERADOR'] . '_' . $datosEmpresa['PERIODO'] . '_' . $datosEmpresa['TIPOPLANILLA'] . '_TIPO_2.txt';

        $archivo = $ruta . '/' . $nombreArchivo;

        $contenido = null;

        /* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - *
         *          REGISTRO TIPO 1          *
         * - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

        $campo1 = '01';
        $campo2 = str_pad($datosEmpresa['MPLA'], 1);
        $campo3 = str_pad('0001', 4);
        $campo4 = str_pad($datosEmpresa['RASO'], 200);
        $campo5 = str_pad($datosEmpresa['TIDE'], 2);
        $campo6 = str_pad($datosEmpresa['IDEM'], 16);
        $campo7 = str_pad($datosEmpresa['DIGV'], 1);
        $campo8 = str_pad($datosEmpresa['TIPOPLANILLA'], 1);
        $campo9 = str_pad($datosEmpresa['PLANILLAANTERIOR'], 10);
        $campo10 = str_pad($datosEmpresa['FECHAPLANILLAANT'], 10);
        $campo11 = str_pad($datosEmpresa['PRESENTACION'], 1);
        $campo12 = str_pad($datosEmpresa['CODSUCURSAL'], 10);
        $campo13 = str_pad($datosEmpresa['NOMSUCURSAL'], 40);
        $campo14 = str_pad($datosEmpresa['CARL'], 6);
        $campo15 = str_pad($datosEmpresa['PERIODO'], 7);
        $campo16 = str_pad($datosEmpresa['PERIODOSALUD'], 7);
        $campo17 = str_pad(" ", 10); //PLANILLA
        $campo18 = str_pad(" ", 10); //FECHA PAGO
        $campo19 = str_pad(count($datosTrabajador), 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $campo20 = str_pad($datosEmpresa['TOTALNOMINA'], 12, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $campo21 = str_pad($datosEmpresa['TAPO'], 2);
        $campo22 = str_pad($datosEmpresa['OPERADOR'], 2);

        $contenido .= $campo1 . $campo2 . $campo3 . $campo4 . $campo5 . $campo6 . $campo7 . $campo8 . $campo9 . $campo10 . $campo11 . $campo12 . $campo13 . $campo14 . $campo15 . $campo16 . $campo17 . $campo18 . $campo19 . $campo20 . $campo21 . $campo22;

        Storage::append($archivo, $contenido);
```

2. I attach my source code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kXOq.png)

Only for the first row, the others one it's OK.

Comment: If you use Storage::put () the second parameter is the content. Try to dd the content and see what you put in the file.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with how the file is created, try using `Storage::put` instead and see if its different.

Comment: With Storage::put , nothing :( Same spaces....Help :(

Comment: it seems you don't need this `$contenido = null;` since you could just do `$contenido = $campo1 . $campo2 . $campo3 ...` at the end. And one question that arises is how did you create the file? Did you do it through the facade storage with which method?

Comment: Yes, @porloscerrosΨ, I created the File with the Storage Facades, it is to end to file, only don't show it in the example. I will try your solution. Thanks

Comment: The `append` method allows you to write to the end of an existing file and not create a file. To create the file you should use put method `Storage::put($archivo, $campo1 . $campo2 . $campo3 ... );`